# How to modify objects in a List<? extends MyObject> while iterating?

Tags: java, iteration, listiterator

I am trying to modify a field in select objects in a List but I am unable to find a way to do so, using plain Iterator because it has no `set()` method.

I tried using ArrayListIterator that provides a `set()` method, but this throws a casting exception. Is there way to workaround this?

```
   Iterator it = topContainer.subList.iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
      MyObject curObj = (MyObject) it.next();
      if ( !curObj.getLabel().contains("/") ) {
           String newLabel = curObj.getLabel() + "/";
           curObj.setLabel(newLabel);
           ((ArrayListIterator) it).set(curObj)
       }
    }
```

I expect the original current object in the list to be set without incident, but instead I am getting this exception:

> java.util.ArrayList$itr cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.ArrayListIterator

What is the proper way of accomplishing what I would like to do?

Comment: `curObj.setLabel(newLabel);` should be enough. All you want is change the label on the object, you shouldn't need to overwrite the object with itself in the list

Comment: `MyObject` class have a setter for field Label ? `setLabel` ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you can just iterate through the arraylist and modify the object. you do not need to set the object to the iterator

Comment: @ernest_k Your suggestion only modifies a copy of the original object fetched from the list via the iterator. I will not modify the original.

Comment: @Introspective It does modify the original. `MyObject` is a class right?

Comment: @KhalidShah Yes, MyObject class have a setLabel() setter for the field label. Otherwise the code will not even compile.

Comment: @Introspective That's not how it works. Iterators don't provide you with a copy of the object, they provide the object itself. If you edit a property, this will be saved in the original object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to call `set` at all. You can just call `setLabel` on `curObj`:

```
// please, don't use raw types!
Iterator<? extends MyObject> it = topContainer.subList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   MyObject curObj = it.next();
   if ( !curObj.getLabel().contains("/") ) {
       String newLabel = curObj.getLabel() + "/";
       curObj.setLabel(newLabel);
   }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I do not need to call `set` at all. Modification works on the original object. I probably missed the `Iterator<? extends MyObject> it` which resulted in a different exception being thrown and that confused me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be following (works not for java versions below 1.5):

```
for(MyObject curObj : topContainer.subList){
    if (!curObj.getLabel().contains("/")) {
       String newLabel = curObj.getLabel() + "/";
       curObj.setLabel(newLabel);
    }
}
```

This is an enhanced for-loop, and it does call the iterator too, but you can't see it.

Also setting the object via the iterator is not needed, as you're working with references to `Object`s in Java, when you edit an object, everyone that has a pointer to that object, will see the change too. For more you can read this great post: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

> If you can't use Java 5, then you're missing out big time. The current java version is **11**. So you should really, really, really, upgrade your JDK

Answer (score 2):

you just have to set the label. In JAVA 11 you can use streams. it makes your code more readable.

```
List<MyObject> list = topContainer.subList;
list
    .stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(e->e.getLabel().contains("/")))
    .forEach(e->e.setLabel(e.getLabel()+"/"));
```

In java 8 you can use

`(!e->e.getLabel().contains("/"))`

instead of

`Predicate.not(e->e.getLabel().contains("/")`

Comment: why not just use `topContainer.subList.stream()`? no need for `Iterable` nor `StreamSupport`

Comment: What Lino said. Also, if you really want an iterator, why not just `it.forEachRemaining`?

Comment: Also `Predicate.not` is not from the JDK8, where's that coming from?

Comment: @Lino its from Java 11. you can use `!e->e.getLabel().contains("/")` if you are on java 8.

Comment: Rather `e->!e.getLabel().contains("/")`

Comment: @KhalidShah so the sentence in the answer: *In JAVA 8 you can use streams* is not entirely correct, when the example doesn't work in Java8 ;)